# Text element in SVG file - start at top y

Tags: xml, html, svg

This is my SVG file:
`$` 
http://jsfiddle.net/fHdYC/

Why i can't see all text? I want start writing from posx=0,posy=0

Answer (score 1):

The text is put at position (0,0) but for text in svg that (0,0) is where the baseline of the text gets placed. This means that the text will be extending upwards from the baseline (in your example the text ends up outside the visible area due to this).

You should adjust your y position to where you want that baseline to go.

One way is to use `em` units, since they depend on the fontsize. Set `y="1em"` and the text should become visible (depends on your coordinate system/viewBox too of course). See http://jsfiddle.net/8MpyY/.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a4p52/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="2551" height="3578">
<g name="text_group" id="group_lay_29073" >
    <text x="0" y="0" font-family="Arial" font-size="30" fill="#000" alignment-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="start" font-style="normal" >Loremp ipsum</text>
</g>
```

Use "text-anchor" and "alignment-baseline".